# Why wasn't the PreGet event triggered?(matlab callback-function)

Tags: matlab, listener, addeventlistener, event-listener

Originally, this example was meant to validate the AbortSet property, but I've encountered another issue. The problem is that the PreGet event isn't triggering when it should.

```
obj_a=ClassAbortSet;
obj_b=ClassListener(obj_a);
obj_a.Data=5;
```

When I run “obj_a.Data=5;”, the get method is triggered（**[Why？Click here](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/matlab/matlab_oop/set-events-when-value-does-not-change.html?s_tid=srchtitle_site_search_1_AbortSet)**）, and the program jumps to `val = obj.Data;`. However, `addlistener(event_obj,'Data','PreGet',@obj.getDataFunc);` is not executed before this. Shouldn't `addlistener(event_obj,'Data','PreGet',@obj.getDataFunc);` be triggered before executing the get method?
Then, I executed the following code. The program directly jumps to the    callback function - "getDataFunc" .

```
x=obj_a.Data
```

**So there is a question here.Why doesn't the    callback function - "getDataFunc"       get triggered the first time when getting the Data, but it does when executing `x = obj_a.Data;` for the same Data?**

```
classdef  ClassAbortSet < handle
    properties (SetObservable, GetObservable, AbortSet)
        Data=5;
    end
    methods
        function obj = ClassAbortSet(val)
            if nargin > 0
                obj.Data = val;
            end
        end
        function val = get.Data(obj)
            val = obj.Data;
            disp('get.Data called')
        end
        function set.Data(obj,val)
            obj.Data = val;
            disp('set.Data called')
        end
    end
end
```

---

```
classdef  ClassListener < handle
    methods
        function obj = ClassListener(event_obj)
            addlistener(event_obj,'Data','PreGet',@obj.getDataFunc);
            addlistener(event_obj,'Data','PreSet',@obj.setDataFunc);
            addlistener(event_obj,'Data','PostSet',@obj.setDataFunc);
        end
    end
    methods(Static)
        function getDataFunc(src,evnt)
            disp ('PreGet event triggered') %This is the key issue.
        end
        function setDataFunc(src,evnt)
            switch evnt.EventName  %事件名称
                case 'PreSet'
                    disp ('PreSet event triggered')
                case 'PostSet'
                    disp ('PostSet event triggered')
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: *"When I run “obj_a.Data=5;”, the get method is triggered"* Why would it? You're not getting data there, you're setting data.

Comment: @CrisLuengo There is the reason：https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/matlab/matlab_oop/set-events-when-value-does-not-change.html?s_tid=srchtitle_site_search_1_AbortSet

Comment: Interesting. Didn’t know that. Makes no sense, but whatever. Lots of things in MATLAB make no sense. The page you linked shows how the property get method is called, but not the pre and post get events, when you set a value.

Comment: @CrisLuengo This page maybe answer your question:https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/matlab/ref/handle.addlistener.html

Comment: @CrisLuengo Combining the contents of these two web pages, the following steps should be followed. Due to AbortSet=1, when obj_a.Data=5; is executed, it will definitely trigger the get method, and before the get method is triggered, the corresponding PreGet Callback-Function should be triggered first. This is how the process should be carried out.

Comment: @CrisLuengo The reason I'm pondering this issue is that in programming, you can often get the right results due to incorrect steps. Without a deep understanding of the principles involved, you can't ensure that the results are truly correct. I'm curious, how do you typically pinpoint the root cause when encountering a problem like the one mentioned above?

Comment: No, if you look at the example “Implement AbortSet” in the first page, you’ll see that setting a value triggers the get method but not the pre and post get listeners. Those are only triggered when you explicitly read the value.

Comment: “you can often get the right results due to incorrect steps.” Not often, but it’s possible. Thorough testing hopefully highlights the error. But you wouldn’t believe how many bugs exists in software!

Comment: @CrisLuengo “Implement AbortSet”-------I noticed this section of content. His description matches the description in the book I read (the code in question is from the book), and I just find it a bit strange that PreGet isn't triggered before executing the get method. However, if this is how MATLAB is designed, I can accept it.

Comment: It seems to be by design. I guess they decided that the pre- and post-get events only apply when the user attempts to read a value, not when MATLAB internally reads a value to check if it will change or not.